# Clearing Var/Moogento folder

Tags: magento-1.9, magento1.9.3, magento-1.9.3.10

I'm trying to clear some space on our server and I can see that there is quite a lot used up in the  Var/Moogento folder.
Are these files safe to remove? I looked online but couldn't find anything relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Var/Moogento` folder isn't magento's core folder, may be that folder is using for some functionality. so i suggest you to create zip folder of that folder over there using ssh and then you can remove that folder.